# Google OmniAuth for rails giving error "Missing required parameter: client_id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I need some help.

I have followed all the steps correctly to enable a Google sign in using omniauth.

My Config/Initializers/omniauth.rb

```
     require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
     require 'dotenv'

        Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
        provider :google_oauth2,
        ENV["GOOGLE_APP_ID"],
        ENV["GOOGLE_APP_SECRET"]
.......

    end
```

My routes are correct:

```
  get    '/auth/google_oauth2/callback', to: 'sessions#googleAuth'
  get    'auth/failure',                 to: redirect('/')
  get    'signout',                      to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

I have saved credentials properly.

However I am still getting the following error when I click on Google Sign In to redirect to access.

The error is as follows:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Missing required parameter: client_id
>
> Learn more
>
> Request Details access_type=offline client_id= prompt=consent
>   redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
>   response_type=code

Why am I getting the missing client_id error, when my project is properly set on the Google Console, everything else is fine.

Please help me get around this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you set these environment variables??

GOOGLE_APP_ID and GOOGLE_APP_SECRET

I don't think you have, please do set it and then try.

Comment: i did set them up.. but it seems to not respond

Comment: Print logger statements and check if the environment variables are getting passed successfully into omniauth.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks all for the comments.

I was able to resolve it by adding

```
Dotenv.load
```

to the Omniauth.rb